# Introductory Books to Network Theory

Tags: risk, risk-models

Can anyone please suggest a good introductory book to Network Theory which is the area of mathematics that is widely used for systemic risk and contagion modeling in finance. If the book contains some applications in Python, R or MATLAB that would be a plus. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to look at https://www.risk.net/network-theory-and-financial-risk ( https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/our-book-network-theory-financial-risk-out-march-kimmo-soram%C3%A4ki/ )

Comment: You may also like https://www.amazon.com/dp/9811383219 and https://www.amazon.com/dp/1843764156

Comment: Dear @DimitriVulis, thank you so much for the suggestions I'll definitely check them. I really apologize for the late response. Thank you so much again.

Comment: You're very welcome! I also found these IMF papers on interconnectedness helpful: https://www.imf.org/-/media/Files/Publications/WP/2019/wpiea2019220-print-pdf.ashx and https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/wp/2013/wp13199.pdf